# Exchange apache2 for nginx problem

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, nginx

I installed apache2 and now I wont use nginx now. I could reached my html page on local network on 192.168.1.11.

The html file is saved in  `var/www/html/index.html`. Now I installed nginx. I try to uninstall apache by these commands:

1. `sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. `sudo rm -r apache2`

I thought, now is my apache server uninstalled but when I reach 192.168.1.11 I reach my old html page saved in `/var/www/html/`. I googled that nginx default public www location is `/usr/share/nginx/html/`.

My questions:

1. Why do I reach the html created for apache?
2. How can I be sure I uninstalled all apache packages, directories etc.?
3. Can I just delete the `www` directory in `/var/` ?
4. How can I reach the html page saved in nginx default public www location?

   sudo lsof -i:443
   nginx 543 root 7u IPv4 9117 0t0 TCP *:https(LISTEN)
   nginx 544 www-data 7u IPv4 9117 0t0 TCP *:https (LISTEN)
   nginx 545 www-data 7u IPv4 9117 0t0 TCP *:https (LISTEN)
   nginx 548 www-data 7u IPv4 9117 0t0 TCP *:https (LISTEN)
   nginx 549 www-data 7u IPv4 9117 0t0 TCP *:https (LISTEN)

   sudo lsof -i:80
   nginx 543 root 6u IPv4 9116 0t0 TCP *:http(LISTEN)
   nginx 544 www-data 6u IPv4 9116 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
   nginx 545 www-data 6u IPv4 9116 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
   nginx 548 www-data 6u IPv4 9116 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)
   nginx 549 www-data 6u IPv4 9116 0t0 TCP *:http (LISTEN)

Configuration:

```
upstream php-handler {  
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;  
    #server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;  
}  
server {  
    listen 80 ;  
    server_name 192.168.1.11;  
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;  # enforce https  
}  

server {  
    listen 443 ssl;  
    server_name 192.168.1.11;  
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;  
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;  
    # Path to the root of your installation  
    root /var/www/owncloud;  
    client_max_body_size 1000M; # set max upload size  
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;  
    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;  
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;  
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;  
    index index.php;  
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;  
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;  
    location = /robots.txt {  
        allow all;  
        log_not_found off;  
        access_log off;  
    }  
    location ~ ^/(?:\.htaccess|data|config|db_structure\.xml|README) {  
        deny all;  
    }  
    location / {  
        # The following 2 rules are only needed with webfinger  
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;  
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;  
        rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;  
        rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;  
        rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;  
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;  
    }  
    location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {  
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;  
        include fastcgi_params;  
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;  
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;  
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;  
        fastcgi_pass php-handler;  
   }  
   # Optional: set long EXPIRES header on static assets  
   location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {  
        expires 30d;  
        # Optional: Don't log access to assets  
        access_log off;  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Is the Apache service still running? It should have explicitly been stopped when you uninstalled it, but not all packages do so.  Try `ps -AF | grep apache2` and see if it is listed.  Note you'll see one entry for this command - you're looking for additional entries.

Comment: This is listed after `ps -AF | grep apache2` - `pi        5883  2890  1  1067  1960   0 08:21 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache2`

Comment: `sudo lsof -i:80` will show you what's listening on port 80 (assuming you're not using HTTPS - change the 80 to 443 if you are).

Comment: It is possible that the default configuration your distribution (Debian? Ubuntu?) ships sets the default location for files to `/var/www/html/` for nginx, too.

Comment: @garethTheRed actually, I am not sure which port I should listen. I use configuration from this page `https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-owncloud` (point 10). There is configuration where is port 80 and also port 443. Som when i use lsof -i:80 and lsof -i:443 there is almost similar entries. I cannot see where is in configuration  specified the default public www location.

Comment: Sorry, I am new one here :) I added it to the question.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz my distribution is Raspbian. I do not know where is default configuration. I found on internet more directory where configuration should be but they do not exist in my system. I found only `etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: The output of `lsof` shows us that it is Nginx that is running, not Apache.  The next thing is to look at your Nginx config, which is `etc/nginx/sites-available/default`.  So, add that to your post.

Comment: Is that the only configuration file that has been enabled? Anything else in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`?  Download the page with `wget <URL or IP>` and open the file to confirm it is what you're expecting. This is just in-case your browser had cached the previous site.

Comment: There is only one configuration file. I try do download my page, it works fine. I try to reach my page over mozilla and it is work fine. I change the listen port from 80 to 800 in configuration above and when I write `192.168.1.11` my html page is reached. On `192.168.1.11:800` I reach my owncloud. It not work in chrome maybe chrome cached the previous page as you sad? Where is configured that nginx should reach my html page in var/www/html/ port 80? I think, in configuration below is configured just `root /var/www/owncloud` for my cloud over HTTPS. Am I uderstand configuration file correctly?